# html css responsive design several buttons middle 4/0 or 2/2 but no 3/1

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I currently have made my buttons like so (I've taken off the useless stuff to reproduce the problem):

CSS:

```
    .containerWelcome{
        margin: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    .buttonsWelcome {
        width: 200px;
    }
    .disabled {
      opacity: 0.6;
      cursor: not-allowed;
    }
```

HTML:

```
        <div class="containerWelcome">
            <button name="button1" onclick="location.href=something0"
                    class="buttonsWelcome" type="submit"
                    value="something0">something0
            </button>
            <button name="button2" onclick="location.href=something"
                    class="buttonsWelcome" type="submit"
                    value="something">something
            </button>
            <button name="button3" onclick=""
                    class="buttonsWelcome disabled" type="submit"
                    value="somethingelse0">somethingelse0
            </button>
            <button name="button4" onclick=""
                    class="buttonsWelcome disabled" type="submit"
                    value="somethingelse1">somethingelse1
            </button>
        </div>
```

And if I don't zoom in, I have the four buttons next to each other. Which is good.
[image]
If I zoom in a little bit or if I'm on another smaller laptop I have 3 buttons and one below them. Which is sort of ugly.
[image]
If I zoom even more, I have 2 buttons on top of 2 others one. Which is good. Except, they're not perfectly centered, which is a bit weird. I guess that's because they're at the left of the container?
[image]

My main issue is: I would like to go from 4 buttons to 2 on top of the center container and 2 at the bottom of the center container WITHOUT having the awkard stage where there are 3 buttons on top of the center container and one at the botton of the center container.

I also am looking for a way to center the buttons in the center of the container, but that's less important I guess.

Comment: Have you investigated flex or grid?

Comment: Not really, I'm not familiar / almost never heard of them. Would it be suitable for my problem?

Comment: Have a look at the documentation and play around with it. flex is likely to be useful here I think.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ helped me a lot, if that can help someone else in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code:

```
.containerWelcome{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display:flex;
  
}
.buttonsWelcome {
  width: 200px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px)  {
  .containerWelcome{
     flex-wrap: wrap;
  }

  .buttonsWelcome {
    flex: 50%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is to just use display flex, don't worry it's to simple to learn, check the solution below and replace your .containerWelcome style with it.

```
.containerWelcome {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 410px;
  margin-inline: auto;
  gap: 5px;
}
```

Comment: I've added     `position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` to make it work but it does thanks!